# Google Earth Engine - qualityMosaic() opposite

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a way to calculate the opposite of what the qualityMosaic() does to an ImageCollection?
That is to minimize a selected column (for example an added layer "ndvi") but keep the rest of the original bands associated with that ndvi (all from the same DATE). 
Input= ImageCollection, Output= Single Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply the same algorithm as `qualityMosaic()` except to pick the image with the *smallest* "quality" value instead of the *largest*.

In that case, all you need to do is **negate the value.** For example, the quality mosaic example script (which doesn't use the built-in algorithm but works the same way) adds the quality band to the collection like this:

```
var withNd = l7.map(function(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).addBands(image);
});
```

If I change that to

```
var withNd = l7.map(function(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).multiply(-1).addBands(image);
});
```

then I get cloudy pixels instead of green pixels.

---

If you want to do further processing with the quality value without it being negated, you could negate it again, or you could add a band for the qualityMosaic to use that is separate from the quality band.

Here's a runnable example of setting up both versions, modified from the Quality Mosaic example script:

```
var l7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1')
    .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01');

var withNd = l7.map(function(image) {
  var nd = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']);
  return image
    .addBands(nd)
    .addBands(nd.multiply(-1).rename('inv_nd'));
});

function addQualityMosaicLayer(qualityBandName) {
  var greenest = withNd.qualityMosaic(qualityBandName);
  var rgb = greenest.select(['B3', 'B2', 'B1']);
  Map.addLayer(rgb, {gain: [1.4, 1.4, 1.1]}, 'Using ' + qualityBandName);
}
addQualityMosaicLayer('nd');
addQualityMosaicLayer('inv_nd');

Map.setCenter(-90.08789, 16.38339, 11);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/25a70cf8008ef4f13bc5f1a9ca6f732e

In this script the `nd` band of `greenest` is the normalized difference value, whether or not the negated value was used to make the mosaic.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. By the way, interesting function "addQualityMosaicLayer()"

Comment: @AlfonsodeLara Even for a quick demo or experiment, it's handy to define functions for repeated sections, because it means you can try changing both things in parallel without having to write the change twice.